# Asp.net JQuery AutoComplete Not displaying data

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am not seeing data returned from my webservice using the JQuery Autocomplete plugin.

Im sure that this is an issue with the JQuery part of my code. (Firebug shows that I am getting a string back from my webservice formatted like below.)

```
"[\"Component 1\",\"Component 2\",\"Component 2\",\"Component 3\"]"
```

(I did assume that it might be the fact that there were 2 items the same, but removing the duplicate made no difference.)

my JQuery code is...

```
 $('#tags').autocomplete({             
                            source: function (request, response) {
                                    $.ajax({
                                            type: "POST",
                                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                            url: "QuickSearch/QuickSearch.asmx/GetDealerships",
                                            data: "{'s':'" + request.term + "'}",
                                            dataType: "json",
                                            async: true,
                                            success: function (data){
                                                    response(data.d);
                                                },
                                                error: function (result) {
                                                        alert("Due to unexpected errors we were unable to load data");
                                                    }
                                });
                    },
        minLength: 2
                });
        });
```

So can anyone tell me what I have wrong in the success: function ?

Thanks

Edit

```
    var array = data.split(",");
    response(array);
```

The above code almost works, except my drop down box also has the " symbols wrapping each element. I can edit this to strip out the spare characters, but the fact that I am having to do that makes me suspect I havent got it quite right somewhere..

Comment: I think you need to modify your web service so that it sends back json data-- although I guess you could parse the results that you're getting back to turn it into an array. Try to see what's going on by putting alert(data) in your success function-- see if it's a string.

Comment: If exactly the same string as in you question returned from server, why you get data with `data.d`? Which asp.net version you use?

Comment: its .net 2, and the webservice is set to return json data (well it has the attribute [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] applied to it, and that data string definitely isn't xml

Comment: alert(data) returns a list of data, and removing the .d generates a jquery error about missing label.

Comment: It really looks like you're not getting JSON data back. What if you try alert(typeof data) -- is the result string? If you were getting back json data then you would see something like this when using firebug: ["Component 1","Component 2", "Component 2", "Component 3"]

Comment: If I do an alert I get "[\"Component 1\",\"Component 2\",\"Component 2\",\"Component 3\"]", so its almost (but not quite) JSON as I am getting a string back, not an array

Comment: @Matt Yeah-- it's a string. Really sounds like the issue is with the web service not sending back JSON data. Might be good to figure that out. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use this script for success event handler:

```
response($.map(data, function (item) {
     return { label: item, value: item };
}));
```

More here: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response

Comment: That doesn't help, the array returned from my code is a list of strings, not a list of Key / Value pairs.

Comment: Yes I did, it didn't help. I have modified the js to parse the return data into an array and that works. Thanks for trying though :)